# Build error : Trust reason : "NotTrusted" Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am using Visual Studio 2019 for a asp.net MVC 5 and deploy my project to the web server. I got the below error message, please advise how to fix the error message.

```
Trust reason :'NotTrusted' Error: 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\AppCapabilitiesTCH\TCH.csproj'.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.File.GetAttributes(String path)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.Packages.PathTrustVerifier.PathTrustVerifierService.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<<CheckPathAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()'
```

Comment: The rest of the message describes *in detail* what went wrong.  It couldn't find your .csproj file.

Comment: The file should be located at C:\Code\TCH\TCH\TCH.csproj. Could you please advise how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As **temporary solution** I've added project path to trusted paths list.

1. In VS go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Environment** > **Trust Settings** and click *Configure Trust Settings*.
2. Add your project root folder into trusted paths list.
3. Restart VS.